# Duda al heredar de una clase

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, herencia

Tengo una duda.

Os pongo en contexto:

```
package graficos;

import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CreandoMarcos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        miMarco marco = new miMarco();

        marco.setVisible(true);

        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}


class miMarco extends JFrame {

    public miMarco() {

        setBounds(600, 300, /* 600 y 300 indican posicion */ 250, 250);

        setTitle("Carlos");
    }

}
```

Cuando en el constructor pongo setBounds, y setTitle, ¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo, osea se pude llamar a un metodo de una clase padre en el costructor para darle valor a las propiedades hijas? Por que lo he probado con clases propias y no me deja. ¿Es una característica de las clases predefinidas o es que realmente estoy haciendo otra cosa? Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Podrias mostrar lo que vos intentaste y no anduvo.. si heredas de una clase, siempre que tengas acceso, podes modificar lo que sea.. tal vez no tenias acceso? estaba como publico?

Comment: @gbianchi Si ya vi el error, no estaba como publico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás configurando al padre... o mejor dicho a los padres.

`setBounds` viene de Window y `setTitle` viene de `Frame`, la jerarquía está así:

```
 java.lang.Object
    java.awt.Component
        java.awt.Container
            java.awt.Window
                java.awt.Frame
                    javax.swing.JFrame
```

Ahora... si vas al código de JFrame no va a tener tantas líneas de código, esto es porque aunque el código no esté allí, se hereda del padre tal como está; es algo similar a esto:

```
public class Padre{
  protected String miValorSecreto = "mundo";
  protected void diHolaMundo(){
    System.out.println("hola" + miValorSecreto);
  }
}

public class Hijo extends Padre{
  public Hijo(){
   super(); // configura padre(s)
   diHolaMundo(); // llamada local funciona
   super.diHolaMundo(); // igual funciona
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, osea tambien se puede llamar a metodos padre en el constructor sin poner super. no ?

Comment: Efectivamente así es. Pero si lo redefiniste en el hijo y le pones super no vas a llamar a la versión que redefiniste sino a la original.

Comment: OK. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

No existe el concepto de clase predefinida por lo que se refiere a comportamientos. Lo que estás haciendo es correcto, puesto que ambos métodos son protected. Y por supuesto que llamar a métodos protected desde las clases hijas se puede, que para eso sirve la directiva protected.

Por otro lado, llamar a métodos no finales en un constructor provoca un warning, si la clase hija no es final, puesto que si otra clase heredase de esta, y reescribiese el método podría provocar problemas. Tenlo en cuenta.