# Duda con add y el metodo paintComponent

Tags: java

he creado un programa para hacer mi primer 'interfaz gráfica', pero tengo una duda con add.

Mirar el siguiente codigo:

```
package graficos;

import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CreandoMarcos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        miMarco marco = new miMarco();

        marco.setVisible(true);

        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}


class miMarco extends JFrame {

    public miMarco() {

        setBounds(600, 300, /* 600 y 300 indican posicion */ 250, 250);

        setTitle("Carlos");

        Lamina miLamina = new Lamina();

        add(miLamina);

        super.setVisible(true);

    }

}
class Lamina extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawString("Estamos aprendiendo swing", 100, 100);
    }
}
```

El programa me va bien, pero en ninguna vez se le pide esplicitamente que llame al método paintComponent. ¿ Esto se debe a add, o por alguna propiedad especial de la clase o del metodo ?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Duda al heredar de una clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/357592/duda-al-heredar-de-una-clase)

Comment: Y respecto al proceso de pintado automático o manual, podrías checar la liga de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355961/agregar-imagen-de-fondo-a-un-jframe/356018#356018

Comment: Hazle un simple debug. Agrégale un print adentro de `paintComponent` e invoca al método `add`, si imprime algo, es porque `add` invoca de forma implícita  a `paintComponent`. De este modo, te respondes a ti mismo :)

Comment: @MrDave1999 Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de usar el metodo paintComponet usa el metodo paint:

```
    class Lamina extends JPanel {

         public void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g);
         g.drawString("Estamos aprendiendo swing", 100, 100);
}
```

}