# Duda con paintComponent

Tags: java

Estoy comenzando con el tema de swing y awt, y me surge la siguiente duda:

¿En este método que es lo que estoy haciendo?

```
class Lamina extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawString("Estamos aprendiendo swing", 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Estoy usando un metodo llamada paintComponent que recibe como parametro un objeto de tipo Graphics, esto si, ¿ Pero que se supone que se esta haciendo con el super.paintComponent? Estoy llamando al mismo método  dentro de otro que sobrescribe al mismo ...No entiendo.

Comment: Esta se parece mucho a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/357656/duda-con-add-y-el-metodo-paintcomponent?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @RuslanLópez no es la misma duda.

Comment: Entonces agrega los detalles que la diferencian para que la pregunta no termine cerrada.

Comment: La línea: `super.paintComponent(g);` invoca al método de la clase `JPanel`. Acuérdate que `paintComponent` fue heredado de `JPanel`, por ende, puedo invocar al método de la clase base .